# rails redirect_to another controller, doesn't run turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

Now my project run on rails5, turbolinks, etc

My work flow is below.

A_CONTROLLER_VIEW ->  CUSTOM_ACTION -> A_CONTROLLER(customize Data) --rediecting--> B_CONTROLLER_VIEW

But B's coffeescript doesn't running.

This is my code

A_CONTROLLER.rb

```
class AController < ApplicationController
  def move

    @a = A.find(params[:id])
    b = b.new(some_info: @a.custom_info)
    if b.save
      @a.update_attributes(is_complete: true)
      redirect_to edit_a_path(a), turbolinks: true
    else
      render :back
    end 
 end
```

B_CONTROLLER.rb

```
class BController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @b = B.find(params[:id])
 end 
end
```

assets/javascripts/b.js.coffee

```
ready = ->
  alert "come"
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```

If Refreshing page(after move to B_CONTROLLER page), script working.

what is ircorrect my code?

Comment: You need to listen to the event `'page:change'`.

Comment: @Aetherus `page:change`  if adding this line js called double alerting. need delete line turbolinks:load ?

Comment: Yes, you should delete it.